# execSQL SQLiteException near "?"

Tags: android, sqlite

Why doesn't this work??

`db.execSQL("INSERT INTO PARTIES (PARTY_NAME, PARTY_COUNT) SELECT DISTINCT(PARTY), COUNT(PARTY) FROM ? WHERE (Year=?) GROUP BY PARTY ORDER BY PARTY ASC", new Object[] { "Election", "2004" });`

It works perfectly in rawQuery!!

Comment: I've never seen a table name be passed as a parameter before. But maybe I just never tried... Parameters are typically used to allow reuse of the same query plan. So you can just provide a different value filter on each run. In your case, why would the table be dynamic?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what "rawQuery" you're referring to (URL please).  I don't know of any SQL engine which allows parameter substitution for metadata such as names of tables and columns -- only values, nor names, are allowed in parameter substitution.  SQLite is no exception.

Comment: He's talking about the `rawQuery()` method on the `SQLiteDatabase` object: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[]%29

Comment: @fiXedd, tx -- the discussion on the other "answer" makes more sense now;-).

Answer (score 1):

May be it should not?

copypaste from doc:

```
public void execSQL (String sql, Object[] bindArgs)
```

Execute a single SQL statement that is NOT a `SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE.`
For `INSERT` statements, use any of the following instead.

- `insert(String, String, ContentValues)`
- `insertOrThrow(String, String, ContentValues)`
- `insertWithOnConflict(String, String, ContentValues,int)`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html